# How to add a child element that ignores the left marging and padding of the parent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Please take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dd4g4re5/

This is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.a {
    padding-left: 6px;
}
.b {
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var divA = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var divB = document.createElement("div");
divB.className="b";

divA.appendChild(divB);
```

I want to position the child div in top of the
container div, so it completely overlap the parent.
But as you can see, that is not possible because of the
left padding of the parent.

I guess I could do something like this:

```
divB.style.left = -(divA.leftPadding + divA.leftMargin)+"px";
```

But I hope there is a batter way to do that, like some native function in Javascript, so I don't
have to make that kind of calculations.

Also, I would like to avoid setting the child an absolute position.

Comment: Aside from some archaic (and silly) functions on the String prototype, JavaScript itself doesn't have any support for things like this; in this case it's purely a CSS style issue. It's not clear why you're giving the container element any padding if you don't want its content to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Using border-box here will make sure they both fit the desired widths. And you'll want to give the child element a negative left margin the same value as it's parent left padding.

```js
var divA = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var divB = document.createElement("div");
divB.className="b";

divA.appendChild(divB);
```

```css
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.a {
    padding-left: 6px;
}
.b {
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    margin-left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could position the child absolutely within the (relative) parent, like so:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/ouxsdmfc/